# NiftyNet volume sampling

Tags: niftynet

I'm using `NiftyNet` for a segmentation problem. 
To obtain samples from volumes, there is this option `Sample_per_volume`.

Observation: When I monitored the sample location when setting this to "1", I noticed that instead of only one sample is obtained from one volume, it's more like to obtain one sample from one image for *each iteration*.

Hypothesis: If that's true, then it's better to set `Sample_per_volume` to 1 in order to best randomize the sampling process.

Question: Is my observation right? If so, is the hypothesis right? Then why does the option exist if the best option is always "1"?

Answer (score 1):

The motivation for `sample_per_volume` comes from the fact that some medical images can be very large, such that the bottleneck of neural net training is i/o from the disk. In this case, it can be good to get multiple samples per volume for efficiency.

While this is, as you note, not quite ideal, there are a couple of mitigating factors. Firstly, you can set the `queue_length` parameter to be higher. This means that several patches are loaded at once, then are fed randomly to the training. Also, because many 3-d neural nets use patches rather than entire images, 2 patches from the same volume might not even overlap, so for small patches it makes a lot of sense to grab a lot from a given volume.

So, tl;dr: the best option isn't always '1'  because loading data might be expensive.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I understand it! Thank you for the clarification!